# ASIHTTPREQUEST xCode - Crashing when setting delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, asihttprequest

Firstly, the app worked fine before when the request was in the ViewController. I have now moved it to it's own class file to conform to the MVC model, but is crashing when I initiate the request. I've debugged and have narrowed it down to the line where I set the delegate as self. I've edited the class' .h file to conform to 'ASIHTTPRequestDelegate', and still no luck. I do not get a compiler error when the run pauses, however it does point me to his line of code when the method is called:

```
if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:didStartSelector]) {
```

The following code is what I'm using to initiate the request, and this is being called from the ViewController. Any ideas?

```
-(void) authenticateLoginWithURLString:(NSString *)address Username:(NSString*)username Password:(NSString*)password{
    //LoginViewController *loginVC = [LoginViewController new];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:address]];
    [request setPostValue:username forKey:@"u"];
    [request setPostValue:password forKey:@"pw"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: I can't see one at all, it just pauses. Unless i'm looking in the wrong place (console).

Comment: I've added a screenshot, sorry about the size though.

Comment: Does your class implement a `requestFinished:` method, as defined in `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate`?

Comment: Yes, it does. It is as follows:                                       `- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;`  It all worked fine before, it's just when i've moved it to a new class.

Comment: Your delegate is getting deallocated, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's what I thought. You see how on the right of the green horizontal bar, it says EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Basically you're passing self as the delegate, and that object (the self) is getting Deallocated before it can be verified to have the selector. In other words, wherever you're creating the instance of that class you need to make a strong reference to it so it doesn't get deallocated.

Let me know if that isn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm calling it here, how would I set it as strong instead of weak? `databaseConnection* dbConnection = [databaseConnection new];`

Comment: You should be using [databaseConnection alloc] init]; Also, you should name classes with uppercase letters, like so: DatabaseConnection. Lastly, you should make a property in the .h file of this file, like so: @property (nonatomic, strong) DatabaseConnection * dbConnection; and assign it to that after synthesizing it in your .m file.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm aware of the naming convention, I was just half asleep when I created it. I'll try and change it soon. I'll give that a go and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: Do I remove the `databaseConnection* dbConnection = [[databaseConnection alloc] init];`? As Xcode says that I will be hiding the instance variable.

Comment: You should remove the declaration and just use self.dbConnection = [[databaseConnection alloc] init];

Comment: Thank you so much. You have no idea how much I appreciate this.